# How to add hooks in twisted.web (or twisted.web2)?

Tags: python, callback, hook, twisted

How can I add a hook before and after processing a request on twisted.web (twisted.web2 is fine too)? The equivalent of webpy's:

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())
app.add_processor(web.loadhook(my_attach_callback))
app.add_processor(web.unloadhook(my_detach_callback))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some background on why you'd *want* to do this?  I have read the documentation for web.py's add_processor, but it's rather thin.  There are a couple of different points in twisted.web where you could stick a function that would be called.  Which one you want depends largely on what you intend to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

One approach Twisted Web allows is to insert an extra resource into the resource hierarchy the only purpose of which is to run your custom hooks, rather than to actually handle a segment of the request URL as resources typically do.

You can find an implementation of this approach in [twisted/web/_auth/wrapper.py](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-10.1.0/twisted/web/_auth/wrapper.py#L68) which implements the HTTPAuthSessionWrapper resource (exposed publicly in twisted.web.guard).  Note the first line of `getChildWithDefault` which ensures the resource doesn't consume one of the request segments.  This allows it to sit in the resource hierarchy, modify behavior, but not otherwise change the way URLs are dispatched.